# count the number of comments (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, count, comments

i am using this code so i can count the number of comments for each article

```
SELECT *, COUNT(comment_id) as count
FROM article_comments
WHERE article_id =colname
GROUP BY article_id
```

this is what my comment table look like

http://i54.tinypic.com/2cdu3dk.png

i want to save these number in another table (the articles table.. each number next to it's article ) like this

http://i54.tinypic.com/2dgm82u.png

and when the user enter a comment..the number change automatically

someone help me with the code
or if there is another way to do this

i know it's a long question
but i have been trying to solve this for like..forever

thanx

Comment: what u want is a trigger http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 2):

You could set a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that updates the comment count table every time a comment is added. Or you could simply add the `UPDATE` query right after the `INSERT` query in your comment page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article_comments WHERE article_id =".$youarticleId);

//the number of comments is :
$number_Of_Comments = mysql_num_rows($query);

//save it to another table

$query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable set numberOfComments =".$number_Of_Comments);
```

Comment: thank u for ur help...put i am having aproblem it's said "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Comment: gave you a plus one for being close lol, but you should change it to mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: and technically, you wouldnt need to store the number anywhere, you could just display the number on the page at that point.

"There are <?=$number_Of_Comments?>."

Comment: how can i use WHERE in here  $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable set numberOfComments =".$number_Of_Comments);

Comment: yeah i just modified my post, there was a mistake, sorry :p and for MU_FAM : $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable set numberOfComments =".$number_Of_Comments." WHERE something = 'thisthing' ");

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need a lookup table. 1 article has many comments. Therefore, structure your **comments table** something like this (add an article field);

```
id | article | content
-------------------------
1  | 1       | Comment 1 for article 1.
2  | 1       | Comment 2 for article 1.
3  | 2       | Comment 3 for article 2.
```

When displaying your article, list comments using the following query;

```
SELECT a.id, a.content FROM articles a WHERE a.article = :myArticleId
```

When creating a new comment:

```
INSERT INTO comments (article, content) VALUES (:currentArticleId, :content)
UPDATE article SET commentCount = commentCount + 1 WHERE article = :currentArticleId
```

The **articles table** will look something like this;

```
id | commentCount | content
------------------------------
1  | 0            | Article with 0 comments.
2  | 3            | Article with 3 comments.
```

This requires some work on your part, but it has more benefits than drawbacks.

---

Your proposed solution has 2 large drawbacks;

- COUNT() in SQL does not scale very well and can be slow, normally it can be avoided.
- The lookup table adds unnecessary complexity to your application.

Triggers should also always be avoided. They create "magic" conditions - your database can be changed without you knowing about it. Triggers are often more difficult to change than code too.

Answer (score 0):

on saving comments, try to:

```
  update table_where_you_count_the_comments set number_of_comments = number_of_comments +1 where article_id = theID limit 1;
```

or look for mysql triggers.

Answer (score 0):

you're asking the sql server to select everything and the count id at the same time, use one of them and give it a where close, and Bingo!